# Excel: IF cell contains: "unknown" in sheet A, THEN replace Unknown with value from sheet B, WHERE Value in sheet A = value in sheet B

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

thanks for taking the time to look at this!

I'm busy with organizing some excel data, I made an example to clarify things.

[image: Sheet A]

In sheet A, I have some names and the state of that name. For some names the state is: "Unknown"
When this is the case, i want to replace "Unknown" with a value from sheet B.

Problem is sheet B is in a different order, so i want to match names first, if the names match, "Unknown" should be replaced with the state of sheet B

[image: Sheet B]

Hopefully my question is clear enough.

I tried a few things, but couldn't figure out the match part.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: one way to do this is to use the XLOOKUP function in an adjacent column, not sure how you can override constants using formula

Answer (score 3):

If you have office 365, you could try exact match and place formula in the adjacent column,

```
=IF(B2="Unknown",XLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet B'!$B$2:$B$5,'Sheet B'!$A$2:$A$5),B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This will save me a huge amount of time already! :)

Comment: Hooray! Glad I was able to spot that. 

Answer (score 2):

You can't override values with formulas. For that you would need to use VBA.

But with formulas you could make whole new table or extra column. Latter example with `IF` and `XLOOKUP`:

```
=IF(B3:B8<>"Unknown",B3:B8,XLOOKUP(A3:A8,$B$12:$B$16,$A$12:$A$16,"Not found in B",0))
```

Result:

[image]
Adapt ranges according to your sheets and data.